# List files in folder excel onedrive

Tags: excel, vba, onedrive

I need some help listing all the files and a specific folder. I used this tutorial and I cannot get it to work with the VBA.

Once on one drive, will this still work? If I follow the tutorial without VBA, the function doesn't list the file names...

Please help me.

Thanks,

VBA:

```
Function GetFileNames(ByVal FolderPath As String) As Variant
    Dim Result As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim MyFile As Object
    Dim MyFSO As Object
    Dim MyFolder As Object
    Dim MyFiles As Object
    Set MyFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set MyFolder = MyFSO.GetFolder(FolderPath)
    Set MyFiles = MyFolder.Files
    ReDim Result(1 To MyFiles.Count)
    i = 1
    For Each MyFile In MyFiles
        Result(i) = MyFile.Name
        i = i + 1
    Next MyFile
    GetFileNames = Result
End Function
```

Cell Function:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(GetFileNames($A$1),ROW()-2),"")
```

A1:

```
=REPLACE(CELL("filename"),FIND("[",CELL("filename")),LEN(CELL("filename")),"*")
```

This actually prints out

```
https://...../Test/*
```

I had to remove the slash and * for it to work locally. But still not working on one drive

Comment: Can't really troubleshoot this without knowing the path in `$A$1`. Seems to work for me.

Comment: What do you see when you try it?

Comment: Ok I got it to work locally. Not really sure what happen.. but when I moved the files to the one drive, it’s not working...

Comment: I think my knowledge of onedrave was the problem. The users download the drive folders and files and open them locally. So the path isn’t https but C:. I’m moving a system from google sheets and so my knowledge was limited in the excel/ondrive format.